# Execute two fpdf pdf files at once?

Tags: php

I have a requirement where two pdfs need to be created at once. A for loop will not work as one file is going to be a certificate pdf. The next file is going to be an Invoice pdf. I know I am missing something simple or else its not possible to do this. I have attached a simple code to demonstrate what I mean. The files are executed on a form submission.I have made two files and then a handler file to include the two files but still only outputs on pdf.

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Im a certificate');
$pdf->Output('Certificate.pdf', 'D'); //Output of the first invoice 




$pdf = new FPDF(); // This is going to be the second pdf the Invoice
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Im an invoice');
$pdf->Output('This is a invoice.pdf', 'D');
//The problem is it only outputs the first one not this one
?>
```

Comment: You're trying to return to download two files at one request. You can't do that.

Comment: You can't download two files from single link unless they are zipped together into single file.  so a single zip file can be downloaded.

Comment: These will be saved in a server once in production only one will be downloaded straight away the invoice.The Certificate is stored until criteria is met. Is it possible to to this?

Comment: Yes just stop writting both back to the browser. Make one save to disk like you say it should be doing at live

Comment: Assign them to different variable names so one doesn't overwrite the other: e.g. `$pdf1 = new FPDF();` and `$pdf2 = new FPDF();`; but you won't be able to download both in a single request unless you zip them up together and download the zip

Comment: Doesnt matter what I do I changed it like you said and still only does the first action

Comment: Changed output from I to d and d to i